# How to implement EcmaScript2015 promises in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, es6-promise

Is there a nice solution to get rid of Angular [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) promise service and start using [EcmaScript6 native promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)?

Answer (score 0):

I would say rather than using `$q` custom promise, you could utilize the promise return by the `$http`/`$resource` call itself. Because that has been taken care `$http`/`$resource` internal implementation, as they will run digest once their promise `rejected/resolved`.

The only benefit I can see is, by having ES2015 promise is, you could use Arrow function's (`=>`), which is shorter and smarter syntax.

**Code**

```
var promise = $http.get('someUrl');
promise.then((data) = > { //success callback
   console.log(data)
}, (error) => { //error callback
   console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: @STEVER you were right..look at updated answer..? apart from that why you are using custom promise (`$q`), calling any ajax using `other library` for async call.

Comment: You can use arrow functions with angular promises just as well.

Comment: @Bergi correct.. because of `ES2015` we can use `Arrow function` over angular promise too..